# Is it possible to use update method in a way I am using it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have read in many sources that it is better to avoid using update method at all. But I have a situation, that it is the only thing that is working (even update idletask does not help) and looks like the code will not produce memory leak. Here is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


def do_something():

    # ===  there I have some code  ===
    
    root.update()
    root.after_idle(do_something)


do_something()
root.mainloop()
```

As far as I can judge, it is not possible here to be loops and memory leaks. Because I am using after_idle, it will run function again when there are no events left in mainloop to process, that is, in my opinion, will happen after root.update have finished. Am I right or there could be special cases when this code will fail?

Comment: What would you actually do in that method?

Comment: @AKX it is hard to explain. It helps to remove a problem that I wrote about [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76741844/glitches-happen-when-using-place-method-too-often). I tried different ways, only using update works fast and as I want

Comment: Do you want to update `Label`?